# Regex for redirect link?

Tags: redirection

I have a link:

```
mywebsite/in-5-55-hello-everybody-4-you/‎
mywebsite/in-4-54-hi-i-3-trr/‎
```

redirect to

```
mywebsite/hello-everybody-4-you/‎
mywebsite/hi-i-3-trr/‎
```

Can you give me a regex code to redirect, please ?

Thank you very much ! Sorry for my bad English !

Comment: Have you tried creating it on your own ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of the path which is to be matched (and removed) is `in[0-9-]*`
`in` followed by any number of numeric digits or `-`.

e.g.

```
echo "mywebsite/in-5-55-hello-everybody-4-you/‎" | sed 's/in[0-9-]*//'
```